# Breeze: How to validate a property based on another property's value

Tags: javascript, validation, breeze

I have used multiple validators in breeze data property.Below is the breeze schema used:

```
         {
            "name": "property",
            "dataType": "String",
            "validators": [
                  {
                      "name": "required",
                      "context": {
                         //Data for Processing
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      "name": "maxLength",
                      "context": {
                          //Data for processing
                      }
                  }
              ] 
           }
```

In the above schema, the **required** rule will be executed first and irrespective of the result of the first validator the 'maxLength' validator will be executed. So, **even if the field is not required ,the maxLength rule will be executed** and validationErrors will be captured.

Is there any way to run the maxLength validator based on the result of required validator?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make property B required when property A has a certain value, don't use the standard required validator.  Write a [custom validator](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/validation).

Here's an example where a custom validator is added to propertyB that makes propertyB required *only when propertyA is true*.

This is possible because the context argument breeze passes to the validator function includes an "entity" property you can access to check the value of propertyA.

```
propertyB.validators.push(
    new breeze.Validator(
       "myCustomValidator",
       function(value, context) {
           // when propertyA is false, skip validation.
           if (!context.entity.propertyA)
               return true;

           // validate the value is a string.
           if (typeof value !== 'string')
               return false;

           // validate the value is not an empty string.
           return value !== null && value.length > 0;
       },
       {                           
           messageTemplate: "'%displayName%' must be a string and is required when property A is true."
       })
);
```

Comment: No, I am saying ,maxLength validator needs to be executed only if the required validator is true. If the field is not required, I don't want the maxLenght validator to validate the field.

Comment: That perfectly removed the validator from the entity , but I want that to be ignored not complete removal. Because,I will use that validator when the field is 'required' .Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying the field's required status changes dynamically?  Sometimes it's required, other times it's not?  If so, what is the condition where the field is required?

Comment: The field (say fieldA) is dependent on another field (say fieldB).so,based on the value of fieldB ,fieldA will be dynamically required.Once the status of fieldA changes to required,I want to do run the maxLength validator.

Comment: Got it.  I've edited my answer to include an example for this case.

Comment: cool .Thanks for the response . I have another question, if I want to do both required and Maxlength validation for propertyA using the breeze schema (as mentioned in the question) .Scenario is, if Property A is dynamically set as required (error should be displayed if no value is present), if the value is present,then the maxlength validator needs to be run and the error message should be displayed if the validation fails. Both the validators are present in a single property(propertyA). Any thoughts here?

Comment: Customize the validator I provided with logic to validate the max length:  `return value !== null && value.length > 0 && value.length < 20;`